# Reading a character with scanf_s

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, c11, tr24731

I was just messing around with C and ran into this small problem. As you can see from my output I getting '╠' this character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c;

    printf("Do you want to be X's or O's?\n");
    scanf_s("%c", &c);
    printf("You chose %c\n", c);

}
```

See [program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1jjB.png)

Comment: What did you enter as input ?

Comment: this seems to be windows-specific. works with scanf in linux.

Comment: Why don't you follow the documentation of `scanf_s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing `scanf_s()`. Microsoft compilers may warn you to use their *secure extensions* (aka c11 annex k). But, be careful if you do so. `scanf_s()` is not a direct replacement for `scanf()`.

In this case you have to pass the size of the output buffer as an extra argument.

```
char c;
 
scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
```

Having to put a 1 as the size of a single character may seem a bit pedantic. That's because `%c` can read any number of character. `%c` is just an alias for `%1c` (a single character).

By knowing the buffer size `scanf_s()` is designed to prevent buffer overflow (a security risk).

Although, how much these functions really help is debatable. See: [Field Experience With Annex K](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm).

[According to msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-ca/library/w40768et(v=vs.120).aspx#mt19):

> Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size
> to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string
> control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is
> passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to
> the buffer or variable.
>
> …
>
> In the case of characters, a single character may be read as follows:
>
> char c;
>
> scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);

Answer (score 1):

With `scanf_s` you must supply a length [1] :

```
char c;
scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
```

In the case of `scanf_s` think of `%c` to be a special shortcut for `%1c`, which makes this more clear.

MSDNAA states [1]:

> Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type `c`, `C`, `s`, `S` [...].

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [scanf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) says that:

In the case of characters, a single character may be read as follows:

```
char c;
scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
```

So following should work ( See live demo [here](http://rextester.com/XDORC41361) )

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char i;
  printf("Do you want to be X's or O's?\n");
  scanf_s("%c",&i,1);
  printf("You chose %c\n", i);
}
```