# Function automatically looping?

Tags: c++

Ok, so this function is supposed to take results from a user and then give them an option to input more results or return to the main menu main() when they're done.

Everything works fine. the only problem is at the last `scanf` statement before the switch.

Instead of waiting for the users input in `userChoice`, its automatically starting the function over again. Its only supposed to do that if `userChoice` is 'a' or 'A' but it just completely ignores the scanf statement and the switch as well, it seems. What am i doing wrong? Scroll down to see the line im referring to.

```
void inputResults(int gameNumber, int i, int j)
{


    int Results[ROWS][COLS];
        char userChoice = ' ';
        if (j >= COLS)
        {
            j = 0;
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if (gameNumber > ROWS)
        {
            printf("\nJk, Max number of games reached\n");
            main();
        }

        gameNumber = gameNumber + 1;
        printf("\nHow many points did the home team score in game %d?\n", gameNumber);
        scanf_s("%d", &Results[i][j]);
        j = j + 1;
        printf("\nHow many points did the opponents score in game %d?\n", gameNumber);
        scanf_s("%d", &Results[i][j]);
        printf("\nHome: %d  Opponents: %d\n", Results[i][j-1], Results[i][j]);
        printf("\nA) Enter results for game %d\nB) Main menu  \n", (gameNumber + 1));

*************************PROBLEM***********************************

        scanf_s("%c", &userChoice); /*it ignores THIS it just loops the 
                                    function after it prints the above*/

        switch (userChoice) //it doesnt even get to this.
        {
        case 'A':
            inputResults(gameNumber, i, j);
        case 'a':
            inputResults(gameNumber, i, j);
        case 'b':
            main();
        case 'B':
            main();
        default:
            printf("\nThats still not  a valid choice dude\n");
        }

}
```

the values passed into gameNumber, i, and j are all all 0 if you're wondering. They were passed from the main function

Comment: you [can not call `main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238179/calling-main-in-main-in-c) function in C++ code, apparently... Plus you are using `scanf_f()` [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199504/reading-a-character-with-scanf-s).

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++? Your entire program is written in C, including the explicit call to `main()`, which is not allowed in the C++ standard.

Comment: @C.M. How does one use scanf_f right? cause when i type scanf_f instead of scanf_s it says unresolved external symbol scanf_f referenced in function

Comment: *Everything works fine.*  -- This is not legal code.  You cannot call `main()` directly.

Comment: @MixtapeMania did you try reading links I've given you?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My mistake, i am programming in C, because i am able to call main() functions.

Comment: Also, you probably want `break`s in each of your `case`s. Otherwise, every subsequent `case` will be executed after the selected one. (Google `case switch fallthrough`.)And don't call `main()`.

Comment: @MixtapeMania -- Why even resort to calling `main()`?  Just write a normal `while` loop.  Calling `main` is an indication you're missing the point of proper looping structures such as `do`, `for`, or `while`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can try just using a for loop for this function. But will that solve the problem of the scanf char value?

Comment: @MixtapeMania -- The comment section is for comments, so I commented on your code.  The answer section is designated for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read a single character with `scanf_s` like

```
char ch;
scanf_s("%c", &ch, 1);
```

and enter for eg. the letter 'A' and press enter, the 'A' ends up in `ch` but the '\n' from you pressing enter remains in stdin. On the next call to `scanf_s()` this '\n' is read and stored in `ch` without giving you the chance of making any input.

Use

```
scanf_s("%c[^\n]", &ch, 1);
```

instead which will read and discard all extra characters still in `stdin` up to the next newline character.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked. It appears there are more issues but i'll go trial and erroring, it at least fixed the scan_f issue.